# QueryFilter does not work as expected

Tags: java, rally

I have this code that stopped to work as expected. I am pretty sure that it worked at least one year ago, but not anymore. I am trying to check if defect was already open for the same test case and for the same build.

Any ideas? Was rest-api changed recenty?

```
private boolean isOldDefect(String refTestCase, String foundIn) throws IOException {

    boolean oldDefect = false;
    // Query for Test Case to associate later with new Defect
    QueryRequest defectRequest = new QueryRequest("defect");
    defectRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(RALLY_FormattedID, "Name", "FoundInBuild", RALLY_TestCase, "Owner"));
    defectRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FoundInBuild", "=", foundIn).and(new QueryFilter("TestCase",
            "=", refTestCase)));

    QueryResponse defQueryResponse = restApi.query(defectRequest);
    if (defQueryResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
        if (defQueryResponse.getResults().size() > 1) {
            oldDefect = true;
        }
    }
    return oldDefect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Defects have a `TestCases` collection, so there's no singular TestCase attribute on them - thus querying on a single TestCase ref as a query condition would not be expected to work.

You'll need to fetch the TestCases collection off the defect and loop through it to look for the ref of the matching TestCase. Something like the following:

```
    String rallyURL = new String("https://rally1.rallydev.com");
    String wsapiVersion = new String("v2.0");
    String wsapiURL = new String(rallyURL + "/slm/webservice/" + wsapiVersion);
    ....
    // Fetch Test Cases collection
    QueryRequest testCasesRequest = new QueryRequest(defectJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("TestCases"));
    testCasesRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name", "FormattedID", "ObjectID"));

    // Query the TestCases collection
    JsonArray testCasesOfDefect = restApi.query(testCasesRequest).getResults();

    String myTestCaseRef = new String(wsapiURL + "/testcase/12345678910");

    for (int i=0; i<testCasesOfDefect.size(); i++) {
        if (testCasesOfDefect.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString().equals(myTestCaseRef)) {
            System.out.println("Matching TestCase Found:");
            System.out.println(testCasesOfDefect.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
            System.out.println("Name: " + testCasesOfDefect.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Name") + "; " + testCasesOfDefect.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID").getAsString());

        }
    }
```

Comment: I was talking about 1 singular Defect that can be associated with only one test case/US or not be associated at all with the test case/User Story. So my code is correct and was working a while ago.

Comment: TestCases is now a read-only collection on the Defect object, even if there is only one TestCase associated to the Defect. So polling the collection, per the answer, is necessary to check for a TestCase relationship.